# How to link IF specific object from combobox is picked then do something

Tags: c#, indexing, combobox

Class 1

```
 public static class DatabaseDeformacijaArmature
        {
            public static NovaDeformacijaArmature[] GetAllDeformacijaCelika()
            {
                return new NovaDeformacijaArmature[]
                {
                     new NovaDeformacijaArmature
                     {
                         DeformacijaArmature = "20 %",
                         epsilonCelika = 20.0
                     },
                     new NovaDeformacijaArmature
                     {
                         DeformacijaArmature = "10 %",
                         epsilonCelika = 10.0
                     },
                     new NovaDeformacijaArmature
                     {
                         DeformacijaArmature = "5 %",
                         epsilonCelika = 5.0
                     }

                };
            }

Class 2

     var deformacijaCelika = DatabaseDeformacijaArmature.GetAllDeformacijaCelika();

                deformacijaCelikaComboBox.Items.AddRange(deformacijaCelika);


 private void deformacijaCelikaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NovaDeformacijaArmature selectedDeformacija = deformacijaCelikaComboBox.SelectedItem as NovaDeformacijaArmature;

                if 
       }
```

How to set if DeformacijaArmature = "20 %" is picked then do something...
then again if 10%, do same "something" as for 20%. Same thing for 5%

that something will be written below..
thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What did that code do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on why and how to provide a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, useful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private void deformacijaCelikaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double selected = ((NovaDeformacijaArmature)deformacijaCelikaComboBox.SelectedItem).epsilonCelika;

    if (selected == 20.0)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else if (selected == 10.0)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else if (selected == 5.0)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Alternative use the class:

```
public class NovaDeformacijaArmature
{
    public double epsilonCelika { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() //This will be used when rendered by the combobox
    {
        return string.Format("{0:N0} %", epsilonCelika);
    }
}
```

Comment: @antestipe no need to say thank you, but you are welcome

Comment: do you know maby how to set precision?? like... a = something, and a' = something... how to set if a=a' on 3rd decimal  then it is true

Comment: @antestipe no clue if theres an easier way but i tend to do ´if (Math.Abs(a-b) < 0.001)´